# Eigenvalues of complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm taking linear algebra II this semester and the course assumes that students have already covered complex numbers. Unfortunately I take my first analysis course, in which complex numbers are covered, this semester as well. I have already covered the basics by myself, but I'm not really comfortable with complex numbers yet, so right now I'm struggling with calculating the eigenvalues of a complex matrix.

Given the following matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ calculate the eigenvalues of A:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} -1-i & -2-2i & -1-i \\ -i & 0 & -1 \\ 1+i & 2+2i & 1+i \end{pmatrix}$$

$A-\lambda I$ is:

$$A' = \begin{pmatrix} -1-i-\lambda & -2-2i & -1-i \\ -i & 0 - \lambda & -1 \\ 1+i & 2+2i & 1+i - \lambda \end{pmatrix}$$

After applying some elementary row and column operations that don't change the value of the determinant, I obtained, unfortunately I wasn't able to reduce A to upper triangular form:

$$A'' = \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda & -2-2i & -1-i \\ 1-i+ \lambda & - \lambda & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & - \lambda \end{pmatrix}$$

I think the determinant of $A''$ would then be: $$det(A'')=(-\lambda)^3 - (-\lambda(1-i+\lambda)(-2-2i)$$

My problem now is that I don't know how to treat the $\lambda$ in the multiplication of the second term. For example what is $-\lambda(1-i+\lambda)$? Is $\lambda$ treated as $(\lambda,0)$ or $(\lambda,\lambda)$?

Comment: $\lambda$ is just a complex variable. You'll get a polynomial in $\lambda$ with complex coefficients. Also, since $A$ is only 3 by 3, its likely easiest just to do a direct expansion of $\det(A - \lambda I)$ to get the characteristic polynomial, rather than faff around with row and column operations.

Comment: Can you tell me what $-\lambda(1-i+\lambda)$ is please?

Comment: @eager2learn $- \lambda(1 - i + \lambda) = -\lambda + i\lambda - \lambda^2$.

Comment: From the original matrix, it is blatantly obvious that the determinant is zero (first and last rows are multiples of each other). The trace is also zero, so the sum of eigenvalues is zero. You just need to find one eigenvalue.

Comment: @orion Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why the determinant is obviously zero? It's not obvious to me. How does the fact that the trace is zero and the determinant is zero help one find eigenvalues?

Comment: If any set of rows or columns are linearly dependent (in this case, first row = minus last row), the matrix is degenerate and the determinant is zero. Trace always equals the sum of eigenvalues, and determinant is always their product. From this, you see that at least one eigenvalue is zero, and the other two are opposite.

Comment: In $2\times 2$, trace and determinant fully determine the system, while in 3D, you still need one more info. If you can guess it, fine. You can also know what to expect from the polynomial. Or, specifically for 3D, the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^3-Tr\, A\lambda^2+\frac12((Tr\,A)^2-Tr(A^2))\lambda-det\, A $. The only nonobvious term to calculate is $Tr (A^2)=$ row1*col1 + row2*col2 + row3*col3 (these are dot products of rows and columns).